# Sprite Nodes rendering randomly...HELP needed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

It's my first post right here and I couldn't find an answer relating to some other problems similar like this one.

So, the problem is, I'm developing a game but it's behaving very weird on this project on the simulator and also on my iOS device. The Sprite Nodes sometimes appear, and sometimes not. It's like a random. I see the node counter on the screen is adding them, but I don't see the sprites. I have 2 sprites added in the didMoveToView method and 1 SKNode which should behave as a container layer for holding the Sprites on top of the background named as a mainLayer declared in the global scope:

```
var mainLayer = SKNode()
var character:SKSpriteNode!
var didShoot:Bool!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

self.addChild(mainLayer)

let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
background.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.midY)
background.size = self.view!.bounds.size
background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
background.blendMode = SKBlendMode.Replace
self.addChild(background)

character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "character")
        character.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:0.0)

mainLayer.addChild(character)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    didShoot = true

}


override func didSimulatePhysics() {

if didShoot
        {
            shoot()
            didShoot = false
        }

    mainLayer.enumerateChildNodesWithName("bullet") { (node, stop) -> Void in
        if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, node.position)
        {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}



shoot()
{

let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
/*
positioning, physics bodies, etc...this works...
*/
bullet.name = "bullet"
mainLayer.addChild(bullet)
}
```

The physics, the positioning are working great on the scene, as the node counts grows on the screen when I touch the screen, but I don't see them every time I run the app, except for the background which is always present. So I have to restart the game on my iOS device or my simulator a few times and eventually they'll start to appear, and in the middle of the game they will disappear at some points of time and appears again...Any ideas? I'm using XCode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.1.1

Comment: as all the answers note, check the zPositions man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the zPositioning most likely. Set the `zPosition` of your character sprites to be above your background layer.

SpriteKit renders sprites without caring about z order, for speed. You need to set the z order if you want it to be something specific.

```
mainLayer.zPosition = 1 //z position of 1. if bg is 0, main will be on top
```

The reason they appear and disappear is because sprite kit might draw them in a different order on different frames - without position set, its random the order they get rendered in.

Answer (score 0):

If I am looking at this correctly,  a few things could be happening. First problem is your background is drawn after your mainLayer.  This is because your `zPosition` is the same, so it will iterate and draw in the order that it was added (mainLayer, background).  Now your background node size is the size of your view when it is added to the scene,  but depending on your scale mode, your scene size may be changing, so you could have a view that is bigger than your original size, allowing sprites to be drawn outside of the background, and thus appearing.
You are also using SKBlend.Replace.  This means that the source will replace the destination pixels.  Since background is being drawn on top, it is going to erase anything underneath is.